# How to avoid public variable duplicate in c#

Tags: c#, global-variables, duplicates

I have public variables:

```
public static List<CompanyModel1> companies1 = new List<CompanyModel1>();
public List<URL> urls = new List<URL>();
```

I add more values to this variable during a function call

```
public void DataBind_Results()
{
    ..companies1.AddRange(listToAdd.OrderByDescending(c => c.compnMastery1));
}

urls.Add(new URL
     {
         Link = listToAdd.First().compnId1.ToString(),
                          Title = arrProcess[ar]
     });
```

But my code always run twice (I see that when I use debug), I think the reason is it always have page reload. 
Then my variable will be duplicate its values, and when I the data display, I see it is duplicated. How to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you're using asp.net or something. Wrap the "add" function in an

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
    //Your add code
}
```

Comment: I find out that if I put my code inside if(!Page.IsPostBack){} then there will be no result! Only outside of that will show result and it is dupplicated.

Comment: Can you add to your question the code from the entire page?

Comment: Can I send in private ? Like using chat tool here and I send you the link ?

Comment: Just put it in your answer, it can't be that much... I don't have access to cloud services where I am.

Comment: The code from entire page is quite big. Its not really that much but due to privacy I don't want to public all here!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, find out why your page is loading twice then fix that.

Then add code to check whether the lists are populated at the start of each data bind before they are re-populated.

Comment: I agree with your sentence but your second makes me nervous. Absolutely, why is it being loaded twice - but clearing/reloading could potentially be expensive. Perhaps check if it is populated before adding some (if there's no way to prevent it in the first place)

Comment: I can't use checking if the list is populated before adding some, because for the first load, it is already populated few times to make a complete list! Removing page loading twice is quite tough coz I don't know exactly what make it load twice and remove it will cause something or not.

Answer (score 0):

You want the variable to populate OnLoad so do something like this:

Declare your variables:

```
public static List<CompanyModel1> companies1;
public List<URL> urls;
```

The populate them when the page loads.  But not if you're doing a postback.

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            companies1 = new List<CompanyModel1>();
            urls = new List<URL>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I find out that if I put my code inside if(!IsPostBack){} then there will be no result! Only outside of that will show result and it is dupplicated. Is there any way to just check without the postback ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running twice that means, once when you call that function and again when the page is posted back.
Put your code in

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 here.....
 }
```

Comment: If I put my code inside this it will never execute. It only execute outside this.